# Plotting in Pandas will not show all data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot from a csv file using pandas, which so far looks like this:

```
headers = ['Voltage (V)', 'Pixel 1']
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows = 2, skipfooter = 126, names = headers, 
index_col = 0)
df.plot()
plt.show()
```

However on plotting only part of the data is shown, seemingly only the first 10 or so points. Initial version in Pandas:

[image]

Where what it should look like is this:

[image]

(which was achieved by manually removing the junk before and after the data, and then just using the basic csv module instead of pandas). I am new to python so I am unsure whether this is a more complicated issue than it appears, any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`skipfooter = 126` means you are losing the last 126 rows of your data. I don't think this is what you mean to do.

from the doc page:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

**skipfooter** : *int, default 0*

Number of lines at bottom of file to skip (Unsupported with engine=’c’)

Comment: Hi max, what I am trying to do by that is ignore everything after line 126, as there is some text at the bottom of the csv. If i’m using this wrong then I presume this is where the issues lies!

Comment: I see that it is the number of rows to skip rather than the row to skip after as I believed, thanks i’ll try changing it and see what happens.

Comment: Please select as an answer if this helped! :)